# How to use FKs correctly in SQL Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Department`:

```
DeptId
Name
```

Table `Team`

```
TeamId
*DeptId (FK)
Name
```

Table `Employee`

```
EmpId
*DeptId
*TeamId
```

I am making some updates on an old project, but I don't know why the old programmer designed those tables like this (like putting both `DeptId` and `TeamId` in the `Employee` table).

I find this useless because I can get the department from the `Team` table, and there's no need to put both FK IDs into the `Employee` table, `TeamId` is enough.

Is there any other reason that could force me to put both FKs in that table?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell which kind of queries are performed on this database? Are there many queries against `Employee` and `Department` tables?

Comment: @ymz most of the queries are getting some department's employees with some other conditions applied.

Comment: It is possible that the original intention of the author was to increase performance by reducing a `join` action for this common query type by saving the `FK` in the `Employee` table. In my opinion, you should use a query analyzer to check if this extra `FK` is making a significant performance change

Comment: The problem with this design is that if `DeptId` in `Team` is changed, the `TeamId` in `Employee` will point to incorrect `TeamId`.

Answer (score 1):

As the data model is written, an employee could be a member of a team that is not in his or her department.

That is probably possible, for instance, if the employee is temporarily on loan.

My bigger problem with the data model is that the relationships between employee and team and employee and department vary over time.  So, I would have three tables for each entity.  The only relationship in the tables would be between `team` and `department` (because that presumably does not change over time).

Then I would have two junction tables, one `employeeDepartments` and one `employeeTeams` that capture the changing relationships over time.